# Define a template function according to class member variable with typetraits

Tags: c++, type-traits

I'm having some difficulties understanding a piece of code that is using typetraits.

Suppose I want to define a template function that works on some classes that has a member variable `k` of type `uint32_t`. (Other classes will have another template function).

The piece of code I have found is the following:

```
template <typename T>
auto has_member_k(std::uint32_t) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().k, std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
auto has_member_k(...) -> std::false_type;

template <typename MyType>
typename std::enable_if<decltype(has_member_k<MyType>(0UL))::value, MyType>::type MyFunction(/*some args*/)
{
  /*some code*/
}
```

Here is what I understood:

- Regarding `auto has_member_k(std::uint32_t) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().k, std::true_type{});` `decltype` is used to verify that the first expression is valid, the second is used to specify that `decltype` should return in case the first expression is valid.
- `auto has_member_k(...) -> std::false_type;` returns always the equivalent of false type
- if `enable_if`'s condition (first part) is true, its result is the second argument,
  otherwise function declaration is ignored

The final result is that the function is declared only if the class has a member `k`.
My questions are the following:

- (Why) do we need the `std::uint32_t` as input argument of `has_member_k`? I guess it relates to the type of `k` but I am not sure how.
- Is the second `has_member_k` defined only to return a false type? I guess `uint_32` is excluded somehow from the case of variadic arguments
- Why do I need `typename` preceding `enable_if`?

Comment: Notice that C++20 has nicer syntax with `requires` and `concept`: `template <typename T> concept has_member_k = requires(T t) { t.k; }` and then `template <has_member_k T> T MyFunction() {/*..*/}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Why) do we need the std::uint32_t as input argument of has_member_k? I guess it relates to the type of k but I am not sure how.

Its a trick to be able to call either `has_member_k(std::uint32_t)` or `has_member_k(...)` (in case `enable_if` discards the first). When SFINAE does not kick in then both templates could be used for the call `has_member_k<MyType>(0UL)`, but the first is chosen by overload resolution and there is no ambiguity.

> Is the second has_member_k defined only to return a false type?

Yes. `has_member_k<MyType>(0UL))::value` is used for the `enable_if` and it needs to be either `true` or `false`.

> Why do I need typename preceding enable_if?

Because `enable_if< .... >::type` is a [dependant type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) (it depends on the template parameter). In a nutshell, the `typename` is needed to ensure the compiler that `enable_if< whatever >::type` is really meant to be a type (consider that in principle there could be specializations where `type` is a member but not a type). In newer code you'll find the alias template `std::enable_if_t` which does not need the `typename`.

---

Concerning the points you did understand...

> [...] decltype is used to verify that the first expression is valid, the second is used to specify that decltype should return in case the first expression is valid.

Its an application of the comma operator. For more details I refer you to [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

> auto has_member_k(...) -> std::false_type; returns always the equivalent of false type

Note that there is no definition of `has_member_k`. `decltype` is only used to deduce the return type and for that no definition is needed. The function is never actually called. Its not an "equivalent" but it is `std::false_type`.

> if enable_if's condition (first part) is true, its result is the second argument, otherwise function declaration is ignored

Exactly. If the condition is `false` then `enable_if` has no member alias called `type`. This is a substitution failure but not an error and the function is discarded. This is SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error).